# Implementation of Conway's Game of Life in Javascript - Cellular logic issues

Tags: javascript, dhtml

I decided to write my own implementation of Conway's Game of Life, and chose Javascript. It is pure DHTML. I have the basics sorted out, but it seems to not correspond to normal Game of Life behaviour. For example, patterns like gliders aren't 'gliding', oscillators aren't oscillating. I have spent a good amount of time trying various logic and have done over ten re-writes.

So, if I had made the glider pattern, it would just turn into a square still life after one generation.

Here is the Javascript code (sorry about the uncommented code):

```
var chanceOfLiveCells = 0.1;
var gridReference = null;
var gridDimension = 15;
var cells = null;
var cellsAlive = 0;
var cellsDead = 0;
var currentGeneration = 0;

function init() {

    gridReference = document.getElementById('grid');
    cells = new Array();

    drawGrid();
    placeRandomCells();
    nextGeneration();

}

function drawGrid() {

    var gridArray = new Array();
    var counter = 0;

    for(var x = 0; x <= gridDimension - 1; x = x + 1) {

        gridArray.push('<tr>');

        for(var y = 0; y <= gridDimension - 1; y = y + 1) {

            //gridArray.push('<td id="' + counter + '">' + x + ', ' + y + ' (' + counter + ')' + '</td>');
            gridArray.push('<td id="' + counter + '"></td>');
            cells.push(counter);
            counter = counter + 1;

        }

        gridArray.push('</tr>');

    }

    grid = gridArray.join('');
    gridReference.innerHTML = grid;

}

function nextGeneration() {

    currentGeneration = currentGeneration + 1;

    for(var x = 0; x <= gridDimension - 1; x = x + 1) {

        for(var y = 0; y <= gridDimension - 1; y = y + 1) {

            var neighbours = cellNeighbourCount(x, y);

            if(isCellLive(x, y) == true) {

                if(neighbours < 2) {

                    setDeadCell(x, y);
                    cellsDead = cellsDead + 1;

                }

                if(neighbours == 2 || neighbours == 3) {

                    setLiveCell(x, y);
                    cellsAlive = cellsAlive + 1;

                }

                if(neighbours > 3) {

                    setDeadCell(x, y);
                    cellsDead = cellsDead + 1;

                }

            }

            else if(isCellLive(x, y) == false){

                if(neighbours == 3) {

                    setLiveCell(x, y);
                    cellsAlive = cellsAlive + 1;

                }

            }

        }

    }

    document.getElementById('currentGeneration').innerHTML = currentGeneration;
    document.getElementById('cellsAlive').innerHTML = cellsAlive;
    document.getElementById('cellsDead').innerHTML = cellsDead;

    cellsAlive = 0;
    cellsDead = 0;

    setTimeout('nextGeneration()', 200);

}

function placeRandomCells() {

    for(var x = 0; x <= gridDimension - 1; x = x + 1) {

        for(var y = 0; y <= gridDimension - 1; y = y + 1) {

            if(Math.random() < chanceOfLiveCells) {

                setLiveCell(x, y);

            }

            else {

                setDeadCell(x, y);

            }

        }

    }

}

function setLiveCell(x, y) {

    document.getElementById(getCell(x, y)).style.backgroundColor = 'red';

}

function setDeadCell(x, y) {

    document.getElementById(getCell(x, y)).style.backgroundColor = 'maroon';

}

function cellNeighbourCount(x, y) {

    var count = 0;

    if(isCellLive(x - 1, y) == true) {

        count = count + 1;

    }

    if(isCellLive(x - 1, y + 1) == true) {

        count = count + 1;

    }

    if(isCellLive(x, y + 1) == true) {

        count = count + 1;

    }

    if(isCellLive(x + 1, y + 1) == true) {

        count = count + 1;

    }

    if(isCellLive(x + 1, y) == true) {

        count = count + 1;

    }

    if(isCellLive(x + 1, y - 1) == true) {

        count = count + 1;

    }

    if(isCellLive(x, y - 1) == true) {

        count = count + 1;

    }

    if(isCellLive(x - 1, y - 1) == true) {

        count = count + 1;

    }

    return count;

}

function isCellLive(x, y) {

    if(document.getElementById(getCell(x, y)).style.backgroundColor == 'red') {

        return true;

    }

    return false;

}

function getCell(x, y) {

    if(x >= gridDimension) {

        x = 0;

    }

    if(y >= gridDimension) {

        y = 0;

    }

    if(x < 0) {

        x = gridDimension - 1;

    }

    if(y < 0) {

        y = gridDimension - 1;

    }

    return cells[x * gridDimension + y];

}

function createSquare() {

    setLiveCell(4, 4);
    setLiveCell(4, 5);
    setLiveCell(4, 6);
    setLiveCell(5, 6);
    setLiveCell(6, 6);
    setLiveCell(6, 5);
    setLiveCell(6, 4);
    setLiveCell(5, 4);

}

function createBlinker() {

    setLiveCell(4, 5);
    setLiveCell(5, 5);
    setLiveCell(6, 5);

}

function createBeacon() {

    setLiveCell(4, 4);
    setLiveCell(4, 5);
    setLiveCell(5, 4);
    setLiveCell(5, 5);
    setLiveCell(6, 6);
    setLiveCell(6, 7);
    setLiveCell(7, 6);
    setLiveCell(7, 7);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's no function 'renderNextGeneration()'

setInterval() might be more appropriate and maintainable for what you're doing.

Firefox's 'error console' is a great help in debugging javascript errors.

---

Patching it with this should get it running at least; it does on my system.

```
jcomeau@intrepid:~/stackoverflow/gameoflife$ bzr diff -r18 bad.js
=== modified file 'gameoflife/bad.js'
--- gameoflife/bad.js   2011-05-15 14:09:12 +0000
+++ gameoflife/bad.js   2011-05-16 04:14:40 +0000
@@ -1,10 +1,11 @@
-var chanceOfLiveCells = 0.1;
+var chanceOfLiveCells = 0.0;
 var gridReference = null;
 var gridDimension = 15;
 var cells = null;
 var cellsAlive = 0;
 var cellsDead = 0;
 var currentGeneration = 0;
+var timer = null;

 function init() {

@@ -13,7 +14,8 @@

     drawGrid();
     placeRandomCells();
-    nextGeneration();
+    createBlinker();
+    timer = setInterval(nextGeneration, 200);

 }

@@ -45,7 +47,7 @@
 }

 function nextGeneration() {
-
+    alert("next generation");
     currentGeneration = currentGeneration + 1;

     for(var x = 0; x <= gridDimension - 1; x = x + 1) {
@@ -93,15 +95,16 @@
         }

     }
-
+    
+    repaint();
     document.getElementById('currentGeneration').innerHTML = currentGeneration;
     document.getElementById('cellsAlive').innerHTML = cellsAlive;
     document.getElementById('cellsDead').innerHTML = cellsDead;
+    if (cellsAlive == 0) clearInterval(timer);

     cellsAlive = 0;
     cellsDead = 0;

-    setTimeout('nextGeneration()', 200);

 }

@@ -127,17 +130,40 @@

     }

+    repaint();
+
+}
+function repaint() {
+
+    for(var x = 0; x <= gridDimension - 1; x = x + 1) {
+
+        for(var y = 0; y <= gridDimension - 1; y = y + 1) {
+
+            repaintCell(x, y);
+
+        }
+
+    }
+
+}
+
+function repaintCell(x, y) {
+
+    cell = document.getElementById(getCell(x, y));
+    color = cell.style.color;
+    cell.style.backgroundColor = color;
+
 }

 function setLiveCell(x, y) {

-    document.getElementById(getCell(x, y)).style.backgroundColor = 'red';
+    document.getElementById(getCell(x, y)).style.color = 'red';

 }

 function setDeadCell(x, y) {

-    document.getElementById(getCell(x, y)).style.backgroundColor = 'maroon';
+    document.getElementById(getCell(x, y)).style.color = 'maroon';

 }

@@ -249,7 +275,7 @@
     setLiveCell(6, 5);
     setLiveCell(6, 4);
     setLiveCell(5, 4);
-
+    repaint()
 }

 function createBlinker() {
@@ -257,7 +283,7 @@
     setLiveCell(4, 5);
     setLiveCell(5, 5);
     setLiveCell(6, 5);
-
+    repaint();
 }

 function createBeacon() {
@@ -270,5 +296,5 @@
     setLiveCell(6, 7);
     setLiveCell(7, 6);
     setLiveCell(7, 7);
-
+    repaint();
 }
```

Your logic error is that you are killing off cells as you go through the loop; by the time the code reaches the dead cell that should become alive, you've already killed one or more of its neighbors.

Comment: Just assume that is nextGeneration()

Comment: I would not say it is an error, it is more of a problem with logic, so the error console is useless.

Comment: did a little testing this morning, and posted a patch.

Comment: It is a problem with the logic. The rules I am trying to simulate are:
- If any live cell has less than two neighbour cells, it dies.
- If any live cell has exactly two or three neighbour cells, it lives.
- If any live cell has more than three neighbour cells, it dies.
- If any dead cell has exactly three live neighbour cells, it becomes alive.

I have tested all of these rules, and the only one that seems to not exactly work the way it should is the fourth rule.

Your supposed patch still has the same behaviour.

Comment: So, in words, how would you stop it from killing the neighbour cells? Stop the timer? I am a little confused. Thanks for your help, jcomeau_ictx.

Comment: Also, do you think separating the process in two steps would eradicate this logical error? So, checking what cells will die and which cells will live, then the next step would to be render it. Maybe, I should separate the cells furthermore, by having two arrays which hold live and dead cells with their IDs?

Comment: Also, your update still has the same behaviour. I am going to re-write it, but separate the live and dead cells and also split the process into two, preparing cells to die or come alive, and then render that change.

Comment: I hadn't updated the patch; the decision how to fix it had to be yours. I believe separating the nextGeneration into two steps, as you said, will solve the problem. Perhaps nextGeneration() can set the unused 'color' attribute (foreground), and repaint() can set the background of each cell to its foreground color.

Comment: Still having the same problem.

Comment: I am currently experiencing a different issue. This is the re-write I am doing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012605/uncaught-typeerror-unexpected-behaviour

Comment: OK, but before I tackle that, I implemented what I told you to do, and it seems to work. So I'm going to replace the patch above with what works.

Comment: The patch now works, thank you jcomeau_ictx. I wouldn't mind knowing what was wrong with my last re-write. But, I am going to use the code I originally made with your patch. Thank you!